# replace text without function

Tags: php, string, replace

I've a php question.
I've a php code, it prints some long texts.
I want replace "n" character in output text with "N". I can create a function. but I can't (and don't like!) put my text to a function (because I have many texts!).
Is there any way to replace "n" with "N" without any function???

Thanks ..

Comment: You can pass the text as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to *create* a function, just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace), the built in function for this purpose like this:

```
$output_text = str_replace('n', 'N', $input_text);
echo $output_text;
```

---

**[EDIT]** If you don't want to put your text in a function, because there is lots of text (as you say), do it like this:

```
<?php
 ob_start();

 //..... ALL YOUR CODE GOES HERE

 $FullOutput = ob_get_clean();
 echo str_replace('n', 'N', $FullOutput);
?>
```

This effectively buffers (catches and stores) all your output and at the end get's it and replaces the 'n' to 'N' and echoes it.

Comment: yes, no function need, but I can't add "str_replace()" before any output. I've many many outputs!

Comment: @kikio, use the second method. That way, it will CATCH all your outputs automatically and replace the text in it.

Comment: +1 though I would prefer `strtr` for single char replacements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $newString = str_replace('n','N',$oldString);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) lets you do replacements such as you need. It can also accept multiple find/replace pairs at once, which lets you define these pairs at a central location in your code:

```
$replacements = array(
    'n' => 'N',
    'foo' => 'bar',
    // as many others as you want
)

// At some other point:
$input = str_replace(
    array_keys($replacements),
    array_values($replacements),
    $output);
```