# Replace all text with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I've a php code, it prints some text.
But I need to replace "n" character with "N" by JavaScript (without editing php code). In everywhere (All texts).
How can I do it?
Thanks ...

PS: I was creating another topic ([#4459901](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459901/replace-text-without-function)), but this topic is different!

Answer (score 1):

Before I write this: I don't recommend it. Doing this before outputting to the browser would be your best bit. It's also not great for single characters because it will replace all instances of `n` with `N` (i.e. `<span>` will become `<spaN>`.

`document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(/n/g, "N");`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/x4akZ/

Comment: thanks, but If I want to replace only texts in <span>, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
replaced = str.replace(/n/g, "N");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just to use the replace function, and after your regex, ou must uso /g which means that you want to replace all chars.

```
"non".replace(/n/g, 'N')
```

Comment: it's correct, but I don't print any text with javascript! I need replace all texts in body.

Comment: you have to add it to a variable like: var replaced = str.replace(/n/g, 'N')